# Phonegap playing html5 video on android with file in www folder

Tags: android, html, cordova, video, phonegap

I'm trying to play a video that is stored locally in the root www folder but it will not play. The video starts loading but never plays. Any suggestions?

Unfortunately I am not able to load the file externally as it's part of the scope of the work.

Comment: What path are you using for your media file? Also, have you tried connecting the chrome developer tools to check for errors?

Comment: just a relative path 'video/file.mp4' I'm able to load images this way with no issue, and the video plays on the browser. I can tell the video is being referenced in someway because the size of the player is affected if the path is incorrect.

Comment: Any errors in the Chrome dev tools?